# validation on simple form in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have a simple_form which is not tied to an object. I am using parameters such that whenever i submit a form, it gives parameters to create method in posts controller. Same as form_for_tag.

```
<%= simple_form_for :postFoo, url: {controller: 'posts', action: 'create', user_id: "#{current_user.id}", group_id: "#{@group.id}" } do |f| %>
   <div style="float:left"> <%= f.input :bulletin_post, label: false, placeholder: 'Create new post          ...' %> </div>
   <div style="float:left"> <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-warning btn-sm" , id:   "bulletinSubmit" %> </div> 
 <%end%>
```

Post Controller, `create` method:

```
@post = Post.create(user_id: params[:user_id], bulletin_post: params[:postFoo][:bulletin_post], group_id: params[:group_id])
```

My question is, how to validate the `:bulletin_post` input field to be non-empty before submitting ? This would be simple if it was directly tied to an object using model validation.

Comment: You are making an instance of Post? so why can't you validate it on the Post model?

Comment: my form is residing in another controller's form. So as i cant use @post method outside that class, i am trying to create a record using parameters..is there any other alternative ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding something... what controller takes you to the postFoo form?

Comment: Actually i am having this form in `show.html.erb` in Groups controller.. so when i post this form, it will post the data into Posts/create controller/action. I guess i cannot use @post object in another controller, so i am trying to submit using params

Comment: Simple In your post model add validates :bulletin_post, presence: true

Comment: @deep, does active record validations work for form_for_tag kind ? i dont think so ..it works for only form_for as that form is bind to that object. Here my form works same like form_for_tag where parameters are sent and object is not tied

Comment: in your groups controller if you were to add a line like @post = Post.new to your show method then you would have access to it in your groups show page...   also, validations are run when calling save or valid?.. so since you are creating an instance of the Post model I believe they will still be run when you try to save the model in your posts controller

Comment: @user3334690 let me try and let you know

Comment: so shall i use simple_form with @post object itself then ?

Comment: ya, it works.. this is silly :) thanks